# Pandas, combine strings from two columns for ticks value in plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I need to plot `barh` from pandas dataframe. However, for `y_ticks` I want the index + string from another column. Index has German words and the other column has the english translation.

This is my Dataframe:

```
     count     eng

    -----------------
seit   12     since
mehr   11     more
```

Currently I have this plot:

```
df.sort_values('count').plot.barh(figsize=(15, 8)).grid(axis='x')
plt.ylabel('Most common words')
plt.xlabel('number of Occurances')
```

This puts index as ticks, I want index plus the value from `eng` column, possibly under the index value like this:

```
(seit)
since
```

How do I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set_yticklabels method should do that

```
fig,ax=plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(15,8))
df.sort_values('count').plot.barh(ax=ax)
ax.grid()
ax.set_ylabel('Most common words')
ax.set_xlabel('number of Occurances')
ax.set_yticklabels([x[0]+'('+x[1]+')' for x in zip(df.index,df.eng)],ha='right')
```

[image]